# How to kill a Python thread without communication

Tags: python, multithreading

I have read most of the similar questions in stackoverflow, but none see to solve my problem. I use ctypes to call a function from dll file. Therefore, I can't edit the source codes of the dll file to add any "end looping" conditions. Also, this function may last long (like some printing command). I need to design a "halt" command in case that something of emergency happens while printing is processed. The only way I can do is to kill the thread.

Comment: use multiprocessing instead .... but I assume that like the other person who just asked this you cannot do this for some reason ...

Answer (score 1):

It is never good to forcibly kill a thread. Your program should be designed to cleanly exit from threads.

You can mark it as "daemon" before starting it. If you exit the main thread it will not wait on daemonized threads.

Terminating a thread can still be done in two ways. You can asynchronously raise a Python exception in a thread, via https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html#c.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc (as stated, this requires building a C module or using ctypes to make it work). The other approach on Windows is to call the Windows API [TerminateThread()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686717%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> TerminateThread is used to cause a thread to exit. When this occurs,
>   the target thread has no chance to execute any user-mode code. DLLs
>   attached to the thread are not notified that the thread is
>   terminating. The system frees the thread's initial stack.
>
> [...]
>
> TerminateThread is a dangerous function that should only be used in
>   the most extreme cases. You should call TerminateThread only if you
>   know exactly what the target thread is doing, and you control all of
>   the code that the target thread could possibly be running at the time
>   of the termination. For example, TerminateThread can result in the
>   following problems:  ...

I think this should also be doable using ctypes.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot safely terminate a thread without its cooperation. Threads are not isolated within a process, so unsafely terminating a thread contaminates the process. Please, don't go down this road.

If you need this kind of isolation, you need a process. You can safely terminate a process without its cooperation, though it may leave system objects (such as files) that the process was working on in an intermediate state. In your case, that may mean a print job half-done and a page halfway in the printer. Or it may mean temporary files that don't get removed.